# Using grep command for absolute results

Tags: linux, bash, grep

If we use the `grep` command with `'\<string\>'` the result will be absolute. For example:

File1:

```
test
test2
1test
```

If we use `cat File1 | grep test` the output will be:

```
test 
test2 
1test
```

But if we want to get only first row we must `grep '\<test\>'`.

Here it is the question: How can use these chars with a variable in script? Example:

```
cat file1 | grep '/<$1/>'
```

But this command does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes do not allow variable expansion. Thus, `'$1'` will be a literal `$1`. Instead, you want double quotes. See [this wiki entry](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) about quotes for more.

```
$ foo=test
$ grep "\<$foo\>" file1
test
```

Note that `<\` and `\>` can also be replaced with word boundaries:

```
$ grep "\b$foo\b" file1
test
```

You also don't need to `cat` a file to `grep` – it can read a file on its own.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `-w` to match words:

```
$ grep -w 'test' File1
test
```

In case you have the info in a variable, just use it normally with double quotes as [slhck already explained](https://superuser.com/a/1239457/204979):

```
$ var="test"
$ grep -w "$var" File1
test
```

From [`man grep`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html):

> **-w**
>   **--word-regexp**
>
> Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words. The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character. Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character. Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore. This option has no effect if -x is also specified.